# Problema al poner un div después de otro div usando display: inline;

Tags: html, css

Tengo un par de divs y quisiera mostrarlos uno después del otro. El caso es que he leído que esto se puede hacer usando display: inline; y con el float: left; Si bien en otras situaciones sí que me ha salido usando lo que acabo de explicar, en esta ocasión no me sale.

Lo que quisiera hacer es poner el speech bubble después y no abajo:
https://gyazo.com/b3c39be99e2d0c1ef62566441664c711

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.cuerpoUsuario {
 display: inline;
 width: 50%;
}

/* Etiqueta IMG que contiene a la imagen redonda del usuario */
.imagenUsuario {
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 75px;

 margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
} 

.spanNombreUsuario {
 margin-left: 20px;
 color: gray;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.localizacion {
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.nivelColaboracion {
 margin: 7px 0 7px 0;
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: gray;
}

.cantidadOpiniones {
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.cantidadOpiniones span {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.nivelColaboracion > * {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.nivelColaboracion img {
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.cantidadOpiniones > * {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.cantidadOpiniones img {
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.burbujaComentario {
 display: inline;
 width: 50%;
}

#speech-bubble {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
   width: 120px; 
   height: 80px; 
   background: #5ac4ed;
   position: absolute;
   left:100px;
   /*-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
   border-radius: 10px;*/
}
#speech-bubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid #5ac4ed;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
   margin: 13px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="cuerpoUsuario">
<div class="otro">
 <div class="imagenRedondaUsuario">
  <img src="usuario.jpg" class="imagenUsuario"></img>
  <div class="nombreUsuario"><span class="spanNombreUsuario">Tamara</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="localizacion">Milano, Italy</div>
</div>
<div class="recuadroBajo">
 <div class="nivelColaboracion">Colaborador de nivel <img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/badges/20px/lvl_02.png"></div> 
 <div class="cantidadOpiniones">
  <img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/badges/20px/rev_03.png" class="iconoOpiniones"></img>3 opiniones</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="burbujaComentario"><div id="speech-bubble"></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

¿Qué debería modificar para hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Richard, bienvenido. Tienes muchos `div`. Puedes explicar al lado de cual quieres poner el `speech bubble`?

Comment: Gracias, lo que quisiera sería poner el speech bubble a la derecha en vez de abajo. Tal cual está, pero en vez de que el speech bubble esté abajo, simplemente que esté a la derecha.

Comment: Si, a la derecha. pero a la derecha de "opiniones"? o a la derecha de "tamara" ? o de donde?

Comment: Perdona por ser poco concreto, a la derecha de Tamara.

Comment: Que quieres, una cosa así?
https://jsfiddle.net/1t8wdq2d/

Comment: Exacto, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Voy a investigar qué has modificado y cómo para obtener dicho resultado.

Comment: Lorthas ¿podrías hacerme un ligero adelanto sobre lo que he hecho incorrectamente y en qué podía mejorar mi técnica? gracias